# Install an editor while TeXLive from ISO is installed on Ubuntu

Tags: texlive, installing, editors, ubuntu, linux

I've recently downloaded and installed texlive2020 Image file with mounting .iso and running this command: `sudo perl install-tl` and **it's working very well.**

Now I wanted to install an editor like Texstudio or Gummi from repositories. So I used:

`sudo apt install Texstudio`

But it says it's going to install some new packages including `texlive-xetex`.Many people suggest don't install both .iso and repositories texlive since it cause problems.
Is there a way to install a TeX editors without installing texlive again?

Comment: Create a dummy texlive. There are samples around.

Comment: For ubuntu I can recommend this script which will (even if the github page doesn't say it yet) install texlive 2020: https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu

Comment: @phil-elkabat But as I said, I have installed Texlive and there's no problem with it. The problem is every editor in ubuntu wants to install it again!

Comment: AUCTeX / Emacs don't wants to install any texlive package and is probably the most customisable editor.

Comment: I have gone through the same situation as you, installed TeXworks with some latex-related packages after installing TeXlive over internet. For me, I have simply done `sudo apt autoremove` and got rid of the not-anymore-needed packages. You can also try to remove those packages manually ...

Comment: I simply used `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends gummi` and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends gummi` so it didn't installed Texlive package.

Since it's a recommended packages, not a dependency.

Comment: Generally it is a good idea to build and install the dummy package just in case you forget later on. There are soo many questions on the site where it turned out that the user had two different LaTeX installations and since they chose a suboptimal way to add the upstream TL to the PATH, their editor ends up using the wrong installation.

Comment: @daleif Yes, you're right. But this command just installed Gummi without installing any tex-related packages. it was less than 1Mb. you can check all depended packages [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gummi), which Texlive is mentioned as a recommend.

Comment: this did not work on fedora

Answer (score 2):

## You have to tell Ubuntu that texlive is already installed.

There is a German guide [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/TeX_Live_DVD-Installation/#Paketverwaltung-die-neue-TeX-Live-Version-mitteilen). I've taken the liberty to translate it.

First you install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install tex-common texinfo equivs perl-tk perl-doc freeglut3
```

Then you'll have to execute the following commands (create a folder in tmp called tl-quivs and then change to the newly created directory):

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/tl-equivs
cd /tmp/tl-equivs
```

Next you'll download a fitting equivs-file [debian-equivs-2020-ex.txt](https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2020-ex.txt) and place it inside `/tmp/tl-equivs`. You can use the terminal if you like:

```
wget https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2020-ex.txt
```

Now you build and install the package:

```
sudo equivs-build debian-equivs-2020-ex.txt
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_*_all.deb
```

This should do it.

Comment: Is it like an empty .deb file which fools ubuntu to consider texlive is installed?

Comment: @MohammadKazemi, yes, pretty much. The script (https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) I've recommended takes care of all of this for you. It is really convenient. Maybe you'll use it next year for texlive 2021.

Comment: Is there any reason to install from .iso ? I've just heard it's better than installing from apt repositories. Are there different?

Comment: @MohammadKazemi, you get newer packages and you can keep your distribution up to date. Ubuntu 20.04 is still on texlive 2019.20200218-1 and will probably stay there for quite a while. If you don't have special needs and only use the standard packages, the difference is rather marginal, I'd say. You can check out which version ubuntu ships here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive

Comment: Our go-to guide https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864 also has something about this under **Fake packages**. https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html has something under *Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian*.